# Cannot get Google Map to display on MEAN app

Tags: html, angularjs, google-maps, mean-stack

I am trying to simply get a Google Map to display in a MEAN stack app. If I just run the index.html file, it works; however, when I run the app, the map does not display at all. Is there an error in my code or have I not installed the right packages in order to display the map?

https://github.com/tayrembos/Nav/blob/master/index.html

UPDATE: full code
https://github.com/sammymhowe/NavSpot/blob/master/packages/custom/NavSpot/public/views/system/index.html

Comment: this code does not include any mention of packages. If this is all you have, it's pretty obvious why. It's all HTML markup. You should be using browserify or including the scripts directly.

Comment: @Chamilyan I thought the issue was just something obvious with my html file, but you're right, it's probably the connection somewhere. I have added a link to the full code, if you wouldn't mind taking a look at that file now.

Comment: oh ok. From what I see immediately. There is some major confusion on how to structure a MEAN app. What you want to do is to include the NavSpot package in your index file. You seem to be augmenting the library code itself in some way. Figure that part out first.

Comment: @Chamilyan Yes, I'm not very familiar with structuring a MEAN app. This is what came from the basic tutorial on Mean.io on starting a new app. The structure came from those instructions. How do I go about including a NavSpot package in my index.html file. I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: not index.html ..  I mean in the app.js

Comment: @Chamilyan okay and what do you mean by NavSpot package and how would I go about including it in app.js?

Comment: with the require statement, These comments are not really to discuss this. You first need to have an understanding between what's server and client side. This takes training.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the google map is rendered in the elements panel. If map related dom(that google renders to div) is there then it might be css issue. Also check console for any other errors.